# Mark rolling duplicate by previous value (year) in a grouping variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out whether any `ID` has occurred in any of the earlier years (i.e. `Duplicate` column in `dfo`). If so, I'd want to mark the row as duplicate and include the year in which the `ID` first occurred (i.e. `Year_Duplicate`).

I do have a working code.

> Objective: I want to learn better (or 'pythonic') way to solve this problem in a
>   better way i.e. if there is more condense way to solve it, I'd appreciate any help. I'm not too familiar with all the features we get with `numpy` and `pandas`

**Sample Input**

```
dfi.to_dict() = 
{'Year': {0: 2020,
  1: 2020,
  2: 2020,
  3: 2021,
  4: 2021,
  5: 2021,
  6: 2022,
  7: 2022,
  8: 2022},
 'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 5, 7: 1, 8: 4},
 '$': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3}}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
dfo.to_dict()
{'Year': {0: 2020,
  1: 2020,
  2: 2020,
  3: 2021,
  4: 2021,
  5: 2021,
  6: 2022,
  7: 2022,
  8: 2022},
 'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 5, 7: 1, 8: 4},
 '$': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3},
 'Duplicate': {0: False,
  1: False,
  2: False,
  3: True,
  4: False,
  5: True,
  6: False,
  7: True,
  8: True},
 'Year_Duplicate': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: 2020.0,
  4: nan,
  5: 2020.0,
  6: nan,
  7: 2020.0,
  8: 2021.0}}
```

**Working code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan as NA

dfi=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfi)
dfo=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfo)

df_process = dfi.copy()
df_process['Duplicate']=df_process['ID'].duplicated()

indexes=df_process.groupby('ID')['Year'].idxmin
df_min_year = df_process[['Year','ID']].loc[indexes]
df_min_year=df_min_year.rename(columns={"Year": "Year_Duplicate"})

df_process=pd.merge(df_process,df_min_year,on=['ID'],how='left')
df_process.loc[df_process['Year_Duplicate']==df_process['Year'],'Year_Duplicate']=NA

dfo.equals(df_process) #returns TRUE
```

I'll be happy to answer any clarifications. Thanks for helping me.

---

**Clarification from comments below:**

- `$` is just a number indicating Sales. It could be ignored for
  duplication.
- `Year_Duplicate` shows us the first year when that ID
  occurred. If there is no duplicate, there is no need for
  `Year_Duplicate` in which case we will leave it blank.

Comment: what is the role of `'$'` shall we omit it?

Comment: '$' is just # representing sales. We can ignore it.

Comment: Can yoo add more data to sample? Because not 100% sure if my answer working generally

Comment: @jezrael: I tested your answer against the actual dataset. It works well. The only thing we need to add is sorting, which is fine. I have added it anyway. I'm waiting for others to submit responses. Otherwise, I'll accept your method. It's awesome.

Comment: According to `dfo` the column `Year_Duplicate` is supposed to show the earliest year in which `ID` occured and not just a duplicate of the column `Year`, isn't it?

Comment: @WolfgangK: Yes. Year_Duplicate shows us the first year when that ID occurred. If there is no duplicate, there is no need for Year_Duplicate. I will add this to the Q.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is incorrect IMO. Please take a careful look at the values in column `Year_Duplicate`. That is why I explicitly asked for the meaning of that column.

Comment: @WolfgangK. Yes, you are right. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['Year_Duplicated']=df.groupby('ID')['Year'].transform('first').where(df['ID'].duplicated())
print (df)
   Year  ID  $  Year_Duplicated
0  2020   1  1              NaN
1  2020   2  1              NaN
2  2020   3  1              NaN
3  2021   1  2           2020.0
4  2021   4  2              NaN
5  2021   2  2           2020.0
6  2022   5  3              NaN
7  2022   1  3           2020.0
8  2022   4  3           2021.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['Year'].transform('first'))
0    2020
1    2020
2    2020
3    2020
4    2021
5    2020
6    2022
7    2020
8    2021
Name: Year, dtype: int64
```

Comment: it seems the answer here is not matching with dfo. Could you please correct your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby().cumcount`:

```
df['Duplicated'] = df.groupby('ID')['Year'].cumcount().gt(0)
df['Year_Duplicated'] = df['Year'].where(df['Duplicated'])
```

Output:

```
    Year  ID  $  Duplicated  Year_Duplicated
0  2020   1  1       False              NaN
1  2020   2  1       False              NaN
2  2020   3  1       False              NaN
3  2021   1  2        True           2021.0
4  2021   4  2       False              NaN
5  2021   2  2        True           2021.0
6  2022   5  3       False              NaN
7  2022   1  3        True           2022.0
8  2022   4  3        True           2022.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the column `Year_Duplicate` the way it is indicated in DataFrame `dfo`:

```
dfi['Duplicate'] = dfi.duplicated(subset='ID', keep='first')
first_year = dfi.groupby('ID')['Year'].first()
dfi['Year_Duplicate'] = dfi.loc[dfi['Duplicate'], 'ID'].map(first_year)
```

Output

```
   Year  ID  $  Duplicate  Year_Duplicate
0  2020   1  1      False             NaN
1  2020   2  1      False             NaN
2  2020   3  1      False             NaN
3  2021   1  2       True          2020.0
4  2021   4  2      False             NaN
5  2021   2  2       True          2020.0
6  2022   5  3      False             NaN
7  2022   1  3       True          2020.0
8  2022   4  3       True          2021.0

dfo.equals(dfi) #True
```